# Excel conditional formatting exclude if a, b or c exists in cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I use below code to format if Column A begins with 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 but I would like to exclude three cells that has following text 00a, 00b, 00c.
Can I exlude if A-Z exists? I don´t want all numbers to be formatted for example 800 should be excluded.
All cells is format to text to keep zero at the beggining eg. "001", "099".

`=OR(LEFT(A1;1)="0";LEFT(A1;1)="1";LEFT(A1;1)="2";LEFT(A1;1)="3";LEFT(A1;1)="4";LEFT(A1;1)="5")`

Comment: You could add another **OR** with `ISTEXT`. If the cell contains any alpha characters, it will return TRUE

Comment: @Zac put `123,` and check `ISTEXT` result or Text formatted cell containing a space character` 123`.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij: I agree that in that situation it will throw an incorrect result but OP's question did not specify any of those scenarios. If I understand the question correctly, the only stipulation was that OP wants to omit cells that contain 1 (or more) alpha characters. `ISTEXT` should be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I (roughly) understand the requirement, clear existing CF from and select ColumnA and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(LEFT(A1)<>"0",LEFT(A1)*1<6,ISERROR(FIND("00a",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("00b",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("00c",A1)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

As I suspect the requirement may not have been fully described (see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I have made no attempt to shorten the above, though doing so seems possible.